# How to use override in package.json to update child dependencies

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I am seeing a vulnarability in async and want to update it to `3.2.2`
This is the dependency tree if i do `npm list async`

```
└─┬ webpack-dev-server@4.8.1
  └─┬ portfinder@1.0.28
    └── async@2.6.4
```

So looking at the [npmdocs](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/configuring-npm/package-json#overrides) I tried to add override in package.json as follows.

```
{
  "name": "some application",
  "scripts": {...},
  "dependencies": {...},
  "overrides": {
    "webpack-dev-server": {
      "portfinder": {
        "async": "3.2.2"
      }
    }
  },
  "devDependencies": {...}
}
```

But when I do `npm install` it didn't update async version to 3.2.2 and still shows older version in pacakge-lock.json.
I removed webpack-dev-server package from devDependencies but after running npm install I get empty on `npm list async`

```
└── (empty)
```

Any idea what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use NPM version 8.3.0 OR above for "override" to work.
you may check the below github issue for more info,

https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/4232

Answer (score 0):

You've got it backwards ... you specify which dependency you want to override the version of (e.g. `async`), then provide the version or list of parents and their versions, so it's like this:

```
  "overrides": {
     "async": "3.2.2"
  },
```

OR if being specific:

```
  "overrides": {
    "async": {
      "portfinder": "3.2.2"
    }
  },
```

Comment: You are mistaken- You can see in the mentioned docs that your second example means "portfinder" will use version "3.2.2" but only under the "async" dependency